# Suddenly lost my wireless connection

Tags: wireless, networking, connection

I used to have Ubuntu 13 installed on my computer, it was the only OS in this computer. One day I was at home, connected to my usual wireless connection, watching a show, and suddenly it stopped loading the episode and I lost my connection. From that moment on I am able to connect to other wireless connections, but not my own, my network doesn't even appears in the list. Everything is fine with my wireless connection, because it continued to work fine in other computers. I didn't change my internet provider or any equipment. This happened several days ago, since then I restarted my computer several times, I unplugged and replugged the router cable, I even installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my computer, which I am using now, and nothing worked.

PS - I'm fairly new at Linux.

If anyone can help me, thank you.
Miguel Pinto

Comment: Unplug the power cable from your router for 5 minutes and then plug it back in. See if that helps.

Comment: Oh my god, I can't believe that I just completed my first year in Computer Science and I still haven't learned that turning something off and on resolves absolutely every problem there is. It's strange, I've done this already, but after unplugging the cable I immediately plugged it in again. I didn't knew that the time is stayed unplugged was relevant. THANK YOU

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No idea why this happens but whenever I've used certain 'brand' routers with OS X or Ubuntu, they'll silently drop connection for no reason. Or let the machine connect but refuse to give you any internet access. Try unplgging the router for about ***5 minutes*** and then plugging it back in. Should fix it.